# import data from KML/KMZ file using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

how to import data from  KML/KMZ file using javascript while KML/KMZ file load in google map?

my code :

```
<style>
    #map {
        height: 450px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="capture"></div>
<script>
<script>
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(28, 84),
            zoom: 7,

        });

        var src = "http://iblogbox.github.io/js/gpx/sample/Tour_de_France.kmz"
                    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
                        suppressInfoWindows: true,
                        preserveViewport: false,
                        map: map,
                    });
                    kmlLayer.addListener('click', function (event) {
                        var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
                        var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
                        testimonial.innerHTML = content;
                    });
          kmlLayer.addListener('load', function (event) {
                       console.log(event)
                    });
    }
</script>
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

I try to using load eventlisterner function but it not working.

Comment: The url needs to be a complete publicly available URL.

Comment: @geocodezip

thanks for your reply.Yap your right. The map is loaded but I want to get data from KML/KMZ while loading in google map

Comment: You can't access that information programmatically with KmlLayer.  Depending on the size/complexity of your KMZ, you could look at using a 3rd party KML parser.

Comment: @geocodezip
thanks for your reply. Any suggestions for the best KML/KMZ parser to match the above criteria.